On a specific step in establishing the Kolmogorov's three-series theorem
This is related to the proof of the converse direction of the Kolmogorov's three-series theorem, see Exercise $17$ of Math 275A Note 4.
Let ${X_1,X_2,\dots}$ be a sequence of jointly independent real random variables, with the property that the series ${\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n}$ is almost surely convergent (i.e., the partial sums are almost surely convergent), and let ${A>0}$.
We have reduced to the case where ${|X_n| \leq A}$ almost surely, and established the convergence of the series
$\displaystyle {\sum_n \hbox{Var}( X_n 1_{|X_n| \leq A} )} = \sum_n \hbox{Var}(X_n)$.
Let $X_n' := X_n - {\bf E}X_n$. We would like to show that the sum of the truncated variances $\sum_{n} \hbox{Var}(X_n'1_{|X_n'| \leq A})$ is absolutely convergent (as part of applying one direction of the Kolmogorov's three-series theorem to the sum ${\sum_n X_n - {\bf E} X_n}$). Some suggestions in this regard are appreciated.
Edit: We notice that
$\begin{align*}
        \hbox{Var}(X_n'1_{|X_n'| \leq A}) &= {\bf E}(X_n')^21_{|X_n'| \leq A} - ({\bf E}X_n'1_{|X_n'| \leq A})^2
        \\
        &\leq {\bf E}(X_n')^2 - ({\bf E}X_n'1_{|X_n'| \leq A})^2
        \\
        &\leq {\bf E}(X_n')^2 = \hbox{Var}(X_n') = \hbox{Var}(X_n),
    \end{align*}$
Hence we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \hbox{Var}(X_n'1_{|X_n'| \leq A}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \hbox{Var}(X_n) < \infty$.
